# Are $Q1$ and $Q2$ attracted or repelled to the sphere shown in the figure below?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

Can you tell from the image below if Q1 and Q2 are attracted or repelled. 
Will Q2 only be attracted to the sphere if Q2 is enough bigger than Q1? 
Will the positive charge inside the shell attract electrons interior to the shell and will this make the whole shell exterior positive and would Q2 repel in that case?
Can you conclude that there's a repulsive force on Q2 by using Gauss's Law?

[image]

Comment: I presume the sphere is not grounded? What do you know about the electric field inside a conductor? Can a charge feel a force when there is no field?

Comment: Q1 is inside the shell. When you draw a gaussian sphere around the conductor, won't there be an electric flux, because of Gauss's Law? Won't the dipole induced on the shell attract Q2?

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell from the image below if Q1 and Q2 are attracted or repelled?

No, you do not have enough information.

Will Q2 only be attracted to the sphere if Q2 is enough bigger than Q1?

For any nonzero values of Q1 and Q2 you can compute the distance at which there is no net force.

Will the positive charge inside the shell attract electrons interior to the shell?

Yes. The charge on the inner surface will be just like the situation for a cavity inside an infinite (or grounded) conductor.

Will this make the whole shell exterior positive?

Yes and no. The total net charge on the outer surface will be positive but Q2 itself will affect the surface charge on the outer surface. If you compute how Q2 affects an isolated neutral solid conductor (thus you compute positive charge and an equal amount of negative charge on the sphere but distributed in a spatially uneven way) and then compute how a solid conductor all by itself would distribute a charge of Q1 placed on it (thus you compute a positive distribution of charge).

Then the sum of those two computations gives the actual charge distribution on the actual outer surface.

Would Q2 repel in that case?

That will depend on how strongly Q2 would have been attracted to a solid isolated conductor.

Can you conclude that there's a repulsive force on Q2 by using Gauss's Law?

Since it isn't always repulsive, we can't conclude it by any means whatsoever.

Comment: I had to make a trivial edit to be able to reverse my initial downvote... After I read your answer more careful I realized it was correct.